# Floating point division in ARM7, quick calculation of inverses

Tags: binary, arm, division

I'm using a ARM7 device without any NEON floating point arithmetic hardware capabilities, so for my project I'm having to write in Assembly, I already have a multiplier working, is there any why I could calculate inverses quickly?

Comment: Note that an ARM7 processor and the ARMv7-A architecture are very different things, and the answer may depend on which you mean. As you mention NEON, I assume you meant the ARMv7-a Architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) software floating-point library be good for you?
You'll find the assembler routines for floating-point division under `libgcc/config/arm`.

Comment: Thanks this was the correct answer. The horrid thing was that this was a freshman ARM assembler course which I go no marks for, because this was deemed plagerism.